# decltype does not preserve ref qualifier from structured binding

Tags: c++, type-traits, decltype, structured-bindings

Usually decltype perseveres the ref qualifiers

```
auto a = 0;
auto& a_ref = a;
static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(a_ref)>);
```

But apparently not when it's argument is obtained from structured binding

```cpp
auto p = std::pair{1, 2.f};
auto& [i, d] = p;
static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(i)>); // fails
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qWT574fr9

I'm pretty sure that `i` and `d` are references here. They should be according to [oldnewthing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201014-00/?p=104367) and intellisense is telling me so.

Comment: strange, because [insigts shows it as a reference](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGFycmF5PgojaW5jbHVkZSA8dHlwZV90cmFpdHM+CgoKaW50IG1haW4oKQp7CiAgICBhdXRvIGEgPSAwOwogICAgYXV0byYgYV9yZWYgPSBhOwogICAgc3RhdGljX2Fzc2VydChzdGQ6OmlzX3JlZmVyZW5jZV92PGRlY2x0eXBlKGFfcmVmKT4pOwoKICAgIGF1dG8gcCA9IHN0ZDo6cGFpcnsgMSwgMi5mIH07CglhdXRvJiYgW2ksIGRdID0gcDsKCS8vIE5PVEUgVEhFIE5PVAoJc3RhdGljX2Fzc2VydChub3Qgc3RkOjppc19yZWZlcmVuY2VfdjxkZWNsdHlwZShpKT4pOwoJCn0=&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0). This is a good question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is how it is supposed to be:

> decltype(x), where x denotes a structured binding, **names the referenced type of that structured binding**. In the tuple-like case, this is the type returned by std::tuple_element, which may not be a reference even though a hidden reference is always introduced in this case.

[From cpprefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

In your case, you are using a pair, but i am pretty sure this falls under *tuple like type*.

Comment: `std::array` must also be tuple-like then (as well as structs that can be aggregate initialized), whatever that means